# Mechanism: explanation of final step in synthesis of the thyroid hormones (T4, T3)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

In the following mechanism for the synthesis of T3 (triiodothyronine) on thyroglobulin, what are the factors causing the last step to occur? Does it have something to do with the electron density of the intermediate and/or bond strength? (NB thyroperoxidase abstracts the electrons in the first step so I don't know if it's involved much in the last step)
[image: Mechanism for synthesis of T3 (triiodothyronine)]

Comment: Aromatization might be the driving force? In that case, wouldn't the arrows point in the opposite direction to give the final methylene group on the enzyme?

Comment: I would think so but this is just how they've drawn it. Could you explain how aromatisation drives this change?